# Why is nexus 4 performance better than nexus 5 on genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, benchmarking, genymotion

I was trying to figure out overhead of emulation for different versions of nexus. but it is strange that nexus 4 has better performance than nexus 5!!. I have tried serveral benchmarks and got same results (Andebench, linpack). The VM configurations for both emulations were same. What can be reason behind that.

Comment: it not emulates real nexus4 or 5 .... it is generic emulator but with a different settings(res, dpi, hardware buttons, etc) ... and and skin for n5 has greater resolution ...

Comment: so hardware profile (dual core/quad core) is same for all genymotion devices?

Answer (score 0):

The Genymotion devices are an Android operating system running on a Virtual Box instances. It also do hardware acceleration. So basically, if the devices have the exact same configuration (CPU core numbers, RAM, ...) each instance accesses the exact same resources on your computer.

The difference between a Nexus 4 and a Nexus 5 is the screen size (twice bigger for the Nexus 5). This will clearly influence the benchmark result for all the graphic results.

That's my first impression reading your post.